# Desktop network connection keeps dropping but everything else stays connected

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I'm running Windows 7.  Recently added a new wireless printer (HP Photosmart) and everything was working fine.  Then I started losing internet connection on my desktop.  Desktop is connected to the 2Wire modem/router via ethernet.  Already talked with ISP and nothing wrong with the router.  Tried new ethernet cable.  No luck.  Have tried all the usual ipconfigs (release, renew, flush DNS, etc.).  All wireless devices work perfectly (printer, phone, tablet, laptop) and never lose connection to the network. It's just the desktop, which is the only thing connected via ethernet!  I even bought a wireless adapter for the desktop, thinking if everything is working wirelessly, it would too. But nope, connects for a few minutes and then says not connected.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on??  I've pinged the Ethernet adapter and it's working fine.  The auto IP address for Ethernet adapter is 169.254.191.128.  All wireless devices have IP address as 192.168.1.x.  Appreciate any help. David

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable any other network adapters you may have installed on your computer, as these may be interfering with your main connection. You can do this by right-clicking the computer icon in the taskbar, opening network & sharing center, and clicking on the "view adapters" in the left-hand column. Here, you should see your network adapters. Find out which one has connection, and disable all the others. (Your one that should be the main connection will probably be called "Realtek Network adapter, Local area connection 1, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I only have one adapter (Realtek RTL8101E Family PCI-E FE NIC).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it might help other searchers. I'm assuming David is connecting to his router with a network cable and that the router is wireless. All peripherals are wireless and connect to the 192.168.1.x LAN.

David should have tried uninstalling his network card drivers and reinstalling them. Also possible David has DHCP problems. If so David could set his TCP properties manually, usually like this

192.168.1.100  where 100 or any other number is not being use by another device
192.168.1.1    gateway or router
192.168.1.1    DNS
255.255.255.0  Subnet